# GAE datastore array initialization throw: FK Arrays not supported

Tags: java, arrays, google-app-engine, datastore

I’m trying to save an array object in an entity class, which I would like to store in the GAE datastore. Sadly I get a exception, while I’m trying to initialize the array.

I get this error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: FK Arrays not supported.

My class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    ...
    @Persistent
    private Profile[] players = new Profile[4];
    ...
    public void setPlayers(Profile player) {
        if (pcount.intValue() < 4) {
            this.players[pcount] = player; //Here I get the exception
            pcount = Integer.valueOf(pcount.intValue() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

`Profile` is also a entity class.

What went wrong? How could i fix this. It would be greate if someone could explain it to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate your `Profile` entity as `@Embeddable` and in your `Game` entity to annotate the `players` field as `@Embedded`. For detailed info on JPA annotations take a look at [JPA 2 Annotations](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations). In this way, all the `Profile` fileds will be shown as inline fields of your `Game` entity. If you just want to keep a reference from your `Game` entity to your `Profile` entities, you can use an array of `Key` and not `Profile`. For example,

```
private Key[] players = new Key[4];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If `Profile` is `@Embeddable` could it also be a entity? Something like: `@Entity @Embeddable public class...`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If it can be a separate entity stored in the datastore and also its values embedded in the `Game` entity?

Comment: Yea, exactly. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: I don't think so. Since you annotate the entity as `@Embeddable` and you use it as a field in the `Game` entity, it is not stored separately as well. If you need to have it separately, then the best approach is to use in your `Game` entity a reference to `Profile` by using `Key`.

Comment: I guess to save the key value fort he reference should be enough. Great idea! Thanks very much.